# Lightning experience page rendering is slow

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I've developed a lightning component(actually about 4 sub-lightning components all included on a main component) that queries for records, displays them to a user, and has a form for contact information. I've noticed that the page rendering is extremely slow, and times out for about 50 seconds. Looking in the chrome console I see

> Handling of 'mousewheel' input event was delayed for 55410 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responive.

Is there anything we can do to make the page load faster, or get off the main thread?

Our setup is as follows, we have component mark up, and the javascript controllers which call our helper javascript classes. From our helper classes we callout to our apex method that does the querying and processing and it returns the sorted/filtered results. Then we render the page with the results.

In the meat of the component we query for products and expose them to the user, and they are filtered by a category.
We have iterations in the markup like so:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.categories}" var="category">
        <div id="{!category.name + ' TabPanel'}" class="{!'slds-tabs--scoped__content ' + (v.selectedTab == category.name ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide')}" role="tabpanel">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-no-row-hover slds-table--cell-buffer slds-m-vertical--medium">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                        <th scope="col" title="Part Number">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Part Number</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" title="Item">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">Item</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <aura:iteration items="{!category.filteredProducts}" var="product">
                        <c:productCatalogItem product="{!product}"/>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /TAB PANELS -->
    </aura:iteration>
```

We have a nested iteration which means the category listing will take at most

> O(m * n) time

But this is still pretty efficient and shouldn't take 50 seconds to load with a system of 380 records.

Our querying and processing is pretty straight forward as well

```
Map<String, Product2[]> productsByCategory = new Map<String, Product2[]>();
    productsByCategory.put('All', new Product2[]{});

    Product2[] products = [
        SELECT
            Id, Name, ProductCode, Category__c, Price__c, Kit_Item_Flag__c, Available_for_Quote_Request__c, Quote_Request_Tab__c
        FROM
            Product2
    ];

    System.debug('products: ' + products);

    for (Product2 product : products) {
        String category;

        if (product.Available_for_Quote_Request__c) {
            category = product.Quote_Request_Tab__c;
        }

        if (!productsByCategory.containsKey(category)) {
            productsByCategory.put(category, new Product2[]{});
        }

        productsByCategory.get(category).add(product);
        productsByCategory.get('All').add(product);
    }
```

Have any other lightning experience users experienced very slow load times, or have any tips to make the experience faster?

EDIT:
It looks like most of the time is being consumed by "scripting" by the aura_prod.js library. [image]
[image]

Edit 2:
Created a salesforce ticket and will update this question when an answer is given

Edit 3:

No real solution for this. Chrome analyzing tool isn't an accurate way to determine the time it takes to run the page. It took longer to load the page with it running. Without it running it took about 5-10 seconds. I took away a few categories and that seemed to help as well. theres still an issue with the page freezing while its rendering though.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: We added more products and the slow load time came back. We opened another ticket, I'll update this with the results.

Comment: Salesforce support is still looking into the issue @KiranMachhewar

Comment: I've come across a very similar issue myself, with prevention being the best resolution we've come up with.

What was Salesforce support's final recommendation @Programatic?

Comment: @ScottCovert to limit the # of products shown on the screen and to use lazy loading. :(. They just had a webinar this week on component rendering performance that I would recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Kf_QmYh_4o

Comment: @Programatic I was afraid you'd say that - thanks very much for the video link; I'll definitely check that out!

Answer (score 4):

Been there, done that. The practice shows that XHR is only a tiny bit of the page load performance, the biggest part is actual rendering. every single html element turns into aura:html component. Unnecessary two-way data  bindings consume lot of resources.

1. The first recommendations would be conditional lazy-rendering of every category. In more details: render only first category, attach the scroll listener to vertical scroll, if scroll position is N pixels close to the bottom - load next category. Or simply just start with adding "Load More" link at the bottom.
2. adding pagination to the table will significantly help. In that case  Lightning would need to render only particular subset of the whole long data set, make sure how long the tables could be, cause i saw lightning pages rendering two minutes or more until something will popup (1000 rowsX50 columns). Also make sure how many columns will be in your product, every single columns is miltiplier in performance.
3. if you ARE NOT going to change values in table, i would change by-reference expression, for example {!product} to by-value, for example {#product}, this would skip creation of two way bindings, make dom much lighter. In general, use by-value expressions as  often as possible, try to refrain from by-reference two-way data binding
4. If you ARE going to change values - use inline-edit pattern, in short do not render inputs until user click/double-click on table cell.

Comment: Thanks, these seems more of a workaround than a solution. I really hope we see improvements in rendering with lightning.

Comment: Looks like you could answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192439/lightning-components-why-is-the-rendering-of-3-level-nested-auraiterations