# Is it possible to combine attribute updates into one re-rendering-cycle or defer re-rendering?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, rerender

I have a component basically consisting of 8 `<aura:iteration>`s. For each `<aura:iteration>` I have a dedicated attribute. So 8 `aura:attributes` are controlling 8 iterators. The types of all attributes are all lists of SObjects. For now all 8 attributes are set at the same time in the js-controller.

```
<aura:attribute name="Products"             type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="Battlecards"          type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="FAQAssignments"       type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="RequestTests"         type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="Testresults"          type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="Parameters"           type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="Trainings"            type="object[]"             default="" />
<aura:attribute name="Documents"            type="object[]"             default="" />
```

As observed [also by others](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192439/lightning-components-why-is-the-rendering-of-3-level-nested-auraiterations), massive `<aura:iteration>`s might lead to slow rendering. For some given reasons, I can't reduce the rendered data (e.g. by lazyloading).

What worked for me to speed things up from >10 seconds to some hundreds of milliseconds was to do the rendering via DOM manipulation on my own. I let the `<aura:iteration>`s only insert some skeletal HTML and then I use JS to do the rest (e.g. several picklist with lots of options are created on the fly). Lets call this **post-process**. Now everything is lightning-fast. I **hate** this approach, but I haven't anything better yet.

But one quirk is still there: I do my custom rendering still too often (namely 8 times instead of only **once**).

The problem seems to be that each iteration and it's invocation via attribute change causes a separate rereder-cycle. As said, currently all attributes are set at one time (synchronously). My **post-process** would best only run once, after the very last update is done and the last iterator has been rendered.

No I'm looking for something like a final "all-re-rendering-done" event or mechanism.

**Idea (probably working)**

It would possibly re-render only once, if I used only **one** composite attribute consisting of a list of the 8 SObject[]. Then I could set only this MASTER-attribute once instead of the 8 separate attributes.

But this would complicate things. Now the iterations are flat. They would become nested: top-level MASTER-attribute, sub-iterations on the SObject[]. Hardly viable because even the skeletal structure is too different and better kept separated.

**Are there alternatives?**

So I would prefer to keep them lose. Is there any mechanism to

- either set multiple attributes at once?
- or to combine multiple attribute updates into one rendering-cycle?
- or to defer rendering so it renders only once?

Some more in-deep rendering questions:

- is the rendering for synchronously set attributes also executed synchronously by the framework?
- is there a way to tell inside the re-renderer or at the render-event which attribute update has caused the rendering?

If both would be possible, I could tell apart the last attribute from the others and render only then.

Any other ideas?

**What events I have tried so far?**

My **post-process** is omitted and only console.logs are shown. Each log is a candidate for **post-process**-invocation. Here is my renderer JS:

```
({
    render: function(cmp, hlp) {
        console.log('*** renderer:render'); 
        var ret = this.superRender();
        return ret;
    },
    rerender        : function(cmp, hlp) {
        console.log('*** renderer:rerender'); 
    },
})
```

And some handlers in the markup

```
<aura:handler name="render"                 action="{!c.render}"        value="{!this}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering"    action="{!c.auraDoneRendering}" />
<aura:handler event="aura:waiting"          action="{!c.auraWaiting}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting"      action="{!c.auraDoneWaiting}"/>
```

Handeled like that

```
render : function(cmp, evt, hlp) { 
    console.log('### event:render' ); 
},

auraDoneRendering : function(cmp, evt, hlp) { 
    console.log('### event:auraDoneRendering' ); 
},

auraWaiting : function(cmp, evt, hlp) { 
    console.log('### event:auraWaiting' ); 
},

auraDoneWaiting : function(cmp, evt, hlp) {
    console.log('### event:auraDoneWaiting' ); 
},
```

Now if I look into my console.log I got this for the initial rendering

```
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting
```

And this on each re-render

```
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: *** renderer:rerender 
COMPO.js: ### event:render 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneRendering 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraWaiting 
COMPO.js: ### event:auraDoneWaiting
```

Comment: Are there any relationships that exist between your objects? Knowing if there are any relationships that exist (or that could be artificially created in a logical manner) would be helpful.

Comment: I would say the easiest solution would be to defer rendering via a flag that you check in your renderer and rerenderer. If it's `false` then don't render/rerender. Prior to setting the attributes in your large data structure, you'd clear the flag and set it again when you are done.

Comment: @CasparHarmer how to defer rendering via a custom attribute or anyhow? In my experience setting a aura:attribute in the controller or help enforces a synchronous rerendering immediately. So the knowledge about a way of suppression is the answer to this question.

Comment: Yes but couldn't you about the render in the render function bad in the value of the flag?

Comment: @CasparHarmer I think what you mean is to do my **postprocess** conditionally based on the attribute value, right? That indeed could work. All that leads me to something else: move the **postprocess** directly into the controller/helper. It seems that rerendering happens only after attribute change (and only synchronously) - what I need to know: are there other things which might invoke rerendering - or if rerendering might happen asynchroniosly, too?

Comment: Oops - I meant to write 'Abort' not 'About' - I really don't know what else could invoke a rerender, but I'm pretty sure that these functions are definitely called - and yes, there's no reason why you couldn't put them in the helper and call them from the render functions.

Comment: @CasparHarmer I thought even to go without the renderer at all and put all the DOM manipulation into the mere callback function where I do the attribute updates and put it precisely after the last of the multiple cmp.set() calls. Is that approach too radical or optimistic? In fact I found several of our compos doing that already with no issues... the renderer is complicating things only as far as I see it in the moment

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it for iterations because iterations need to build themselves when their data changes.

You can delay it, as I'll explain below, but it most likely won't work for iterations.

---

Try this.

Put all your data on a state attribute.

```
<aura:attribute name="state" type="Map" default="{}" />
```

Then, edit the raw state object

```
var state = cmp.get("v.state");
state.Products = [...];
state.Battlecards = [...];
state.RequestTests.push('new');
```

Finally, when you're ready to rerender everything, do a set call.

```
cmp.set("v.state", state);
```